# content editor webpart link with different site collection

Tags: office-365, cewp

I have 2 site collection A and B. I have a CEWP in site collection A and a document library in site coll B which contain a script in txt file.
I want to copy the link of txt file from B and put it in CEWP in site coll A.

But its not working and giving below error. How I can resolve this? I do not want to move txt file in site coll A. Its o365.

> error : Cannot retrieve the URL specified in the Content Link property. For more assistance, contact your site administrator.

Answer (score 2):

I had no idea it was the problem in O365. In SharePoint on-premises it works just fine.

**Update:**
I was wrong. CEWP does not work across site collections on-premises.

Maybe, as a workaround, this jQuery-based hacky solution will work for some cases. In your CEWP insert this content:

```
<div id="content"> </div> 

<script>
$(function(){
   $("#content").load( "/sites/SiteCollection/SiteAssets/app.html" );
})
</script>​
```

It does not feel like a great solution, but I hate the idea of copying the same files across multiple site collections.

Comment: SharePoint on-premises has the same issue. This behavior is "by design".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use links across site collections in a CEWP. This is "by design".

I usually create one set of scripts per site collection. Yes, that means duplicates, but then each site collection admin can manage his/her own environment.

A workaround would be to store the JavaScript in a js file (resp. css in a css file), then call those files from your txt file in each site collection.